# Include another controller inside current controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeignitor as separating my website into three like header,body,footer
 I have create header and footer controller and view page.I am facing a problem how to include both the controller in body controller like include('.php') in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html for your pages should be in the views, not in the controllers.

Your choices are;

1) create a view for each section, then call them all from a controller

```
class Foo extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
    $data = array(); // put data in here
    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('main, $data);
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}
```

2) call others views from the main content view

```
// in view for html page
<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
<h1>My Page</h1>
<?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

3) or use a template library, like [this one](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/) for example

If you really want to go down the controller inside controller routes, look at [hmvc for codigniter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC)